# How can I insert a char after n number of characters in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to add a char after n number of elements
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
fun String.appendChar(afterIndex: Int, afterChar: Char): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder(this);
    sb.insert(afterIndex + 1, afterChar);
    return sb.toString();
}

val helloWorld = "Helo world"

fun main() {
    println(helloWorld.appendChar(2, 'l'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace step and specificChar value

```
var charsList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
val  step = 5
val specificChar = '*'
for ( i in 1 .. charsList.length){
    print(charsList[i-1])
    if(i % step == 0)
        print(specificChar)
}
```